# Python Flask 1.0.2 WYSIWYG text editor not working

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a Blog using Flask 1.0.2. So I installed Ck editor 4. It is Working in admin Dashboard but not showing bold text or other.I am using Bootstrap template.

You can Check it in GitHub ( https://github.com/aayush-programmer/flask-blog )

Thanks For solving my Problem.

Comment: Please describe what you try and what you have tried so far. Also read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: look code in github.

Comment: This is not the way to go. We cannot take a lool at a complete project. Please place the code where the problem is in the question.

Comment: <label>Content</label>
<textarea type="text" name="content" class="form-control required" id="editor1" placeholder="Enter Content"required>{{post.content}}</textarea><script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.1/standard/ckeditor.js">
      CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    </script>

Comment: Please **update** your question, and describe the problem.